# C# DataGridView can't display dataset stored in him

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net

I'm trying to pull data from the database to DataGridView3, you can see it on the right column on image below. When i did debug, i saw that DataSet keeps correct values and on first try when i do cellClick on dataGrid1 it shows correct. But in subsequent attempts DataGridView3 does not display DataSet, although in debug there are correct values in DataSet. DataGridView3 display only header titles of tables, not records in database. Also when i click on this headers(thereby doing the sorting of rows) records appears. You can see this on picture 2. So problem is in **DataGridView**, which can't display data which is stored in him. I tried to use `Update()`, `Refresh()`, `Show()` methods on DataGridView3, but it's not helped.

[image: emitting cellClick event]
[image: after clicking on header(sort)]

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection = null;

        private DataSet dataSet = null;
        private DataSet dataSetOld = null;

        private MySqlDataAdapter doctorDataAdapter = null;
        private MySqlDataAdapter patientDataAdapter = null;
        private MySqlDataAdapter appointmentDataAdapter = null;          

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void setConnection(MySqlConnection connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        //creating DataSet
        private DataSet getDataSet()
        {
            if (dataSet == null)
            {
                dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataSet.Tables.Add("Doctor");
                dataSet.Tables.Add("Patient");
                dataSet.Tables.Add("Appointment");
            }
            return dataSet;
        }

        //set connection with database
        public MySqlConnection Connect(string host, int port, string database,
             string username, string password)
        {

            string connStr = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";port=" + port + ";User Id=" + username + ";password=" + password;

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }

        public void FillDataGridView1ByDoctors()
        {
            getDataSet().Tables["Doctor"].Clear();
            doctorDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                 "SELECT * FROM Doctor", connection);
            new MySqlCommandBuilder(doctorDataAdapter);
            doctorDataAdapter.Fill(getDataSet(), "Doctor");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = getDataSet().Tables["Doctor"];
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["id_doctor"].Visible = false;

        }

        public void FillDataGridView2ByPatients()
        {
            getDataSet().Tables["Patient"].Clear();
            patientDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT * FROM Patient", connection);
            new MySqlCommandBuilder(patientDataAdapter);
            patientDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Patient");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = getDataSet().Tables["Patient"];
            this.dataGridView2.Columns["id_patient"].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
        }

        public void FillDataGridView3ByAppointment(string table, int id)
        {

            getDataSet().Tables["Appointment"].Reset();
            if (table == "Doctor")
            {
                appointmentDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT patient.name_patient AS `Имя`, patient.surname_patient, appointment.datetime " +
                "FROM patient, appointment, doctor " +
                "WHERE doctor.id_doctor = appointment.id_doctor AND patient.id_patient = appointment.id_patient AND doctor.id_doctor = " +
                 id, connection);
            }
            else
            {
                appointmentDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT doctor.name_doctor, doctor.surname_doctor, doctor.speciality, appointment.datetime " +
                "FROM doctor, appointment, patient " +
                "WHERE patient.id_patient = appointment.id_patient AND doctor.id_doctor = appointment.id_doctor AND patient.id_patient = " +
                 id, connection);
            }
            new MySqlCommandBuilder(appointmentDataAdapter);
            appointmentDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Appointment");
            dataGridView3.DataSource = getDataSet().Tables["Appointment"];

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,
             DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            int key = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[0].Value;
            dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
            FillDataGridView3ByAppointment("Doctor", key);
        }

        private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender,
             DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedRow = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            int key = (int)dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[0].Value;
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            FillDataGridView3ByAppointment("Patient", key);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Row Selection mode, looks like full row select. ( I don't remember the exact name). Does your CellClick event fire every time you select a row in the first grid? 
So you are trying to get a list of patients in the 3rd grid when you select a doctor in the first grid? Is that right? I think you have to have Cell Select

Comment: yes, it's all right, selected values are true and stored in dataSet object, but for some reason don't won't to display after cellClick, only when i sort, so i think it's need some refresh or reload method to update DataGridView to show elements which it store.

Comment: are u use databind() method??

Comment: no, don't use it, all manipulating with dataGridView you can see in this class